# unable to login into magento 2 in localhost

Tags: php, magento

I recently install magento which version is above 2.2. When I login into magento then its show

> You Did not Sign in Correctly or Your Account is Temporarily Disabled Magento 2

that error...
I also unlocked admin user from php shell cmd

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock magentouser
```

`magentouser` is my magento username

but every time its automatically locked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to create new user:

```
 php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='newadmin' --admin-password='admin@123' --admin-email='info@domain.com' --admin-firstname='faizan' --admin-lastname='beg'
```

Comment: If that did not help, do the next 3 in order without trying to login in between:

    Truncate the mage_admin_user_session table
    In the mage_admin_user table reset failures_num to 0 and first_failure to NULL for the relevant user(s)
    Reset password via the front end option (not directly in the DB)

This is obviously fairly aggressive and should only be done if you haven't been able to get in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you have mentioned generated by magento when you attempt login with wrong username or password. So make sure your username and password must be correct.

Comment: i entered correct username and password, but get error

Comment: Check if one of your extension not creating any error. You can disable extension temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to create a new user using terminal/pUTTY

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='superadmin' --admin-password='superadmin@123' --admin-email='superadmininfo@domain.com' --admin-firstname='super' --admin-lastname='admin'
```

Then try to login with:

user:superadmin

pass : superadmin@123

if this not work try to install modules that you have installed and then check.

Answer (score 0):

Open the path \vendor\zendframework\zend-crypt\src\Utils.php and echo $expected and $actual variable and check both are same or not if both variable are not match then change line no 35

`if (function_exists('hash_equals')) { return hash_equals($expected, $actual); }`

To

`if (function_exists('hash_equals')) { return true; }`

and now you can access admin directly and then do password change or create new admin user and revert the code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user password matches the complexity recommended by Magento.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/password-options.html

I had a similar issue, every time I tried to log in with the username and password, my account gets temporarily blocked. The issue was that I was using a password that doesn't match the requirements set by Magento